# How to design a mutiple level password security for one user

Tags: security, sudo, password, pam, selinux

I am wondering if it was possible to have an enhanced version of `PAM` that implement a login with multiple level passwords.

For instance, I am interesting requiring not 1 but 3 different passwords to be entered consecutively to run a `sudo` task:

```
[user@hostname][/home]# sudo echo ok
[sudo] password 1 for user:
[sudo] password 2 for user:
[sudo] password 3 for user:
ok
```

Comment: What is intended use for this? If does not even boost the security because user has to remember three passwords instead of one - most probably he will be stashing it somewhere in one keepass or on one sticky note or something like this...

Comment: Multifactor security doesn't make much sense in this form (it's essentially the same as one longer password). The security is increased if one of these stages uses a different authentication method. For instance, some admins set up a SMS-based authentication system, where you get a message with the next password.

But of course, the first security stage is to use keys.

Comment: A system with multiple passwords <password1> and <password2> seemed to me to take much longer to crack than a system with single password <password1><password2>. I can also use multiple system encryption

Comment: It is not true, because concatenation of <password1><password2> will actually take longer to crack - suppose 26 characters in alphabet and both passwords to be 8 characters at most. Then with your scheme there are (26^8)*2 possibilities. If you concat the password, there are 26^16 possibilities which is much more. Also mentioning the storage mechanism - an attacker wil be most probably supplying passwords in plaintext so the hash function (or whatever you use) does not matter to him.

Comment: The only way it matters is to have reasonably slow verification to prevent bruteforce guessing - pam already has this, after bad password is entered, there is a delay which does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `ssh` as a workaround.

**Basic idea**

Say you create the users `sudouser` (allowed to execute `sudo` commands) and an intermediate user `middleman`. Neither the original user (`john`), nor `middelman` are allowed to execute `sudo` commands.

We are now replacing any invocation of `sudo` by `john` with a two-step `ssh` access from `john` via `middleman` to `sudouser` with the latter executing the initial `sudo` command. The number of middlemen you put in this chain defines the number of password steps. I'll stick to one in my example.

To undermine people to directly `su` to `sudouser` or `middleman`, these accounts' passwords will be locked. `sudouser` will be given passwordless `sudo` rights, `middleman` exists for the one and only purpose of adding a password barrier.

We will set it up so `john` can `ssh` without password to `middleman` and then use a passphrased RSA-key for `middleman` to access `sudouser`. I.e. the password will be the passphrase of the RSA key. (so note: each middleman needs a passphrased RSA key)

---

**1. Adding `sudouser` to sudoers file**

I assume you know about this - but for completeness reasons I added it. 
We'll grant passwordless sudo commands via adding a line to `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo`:

```
 sudouser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This is a very dangerous user now, so lets deactivate its password (as `root`):

```
 passwd -l sudouser
```

We do the same for any middleman, to suppress directly `su`ing to the last middleman and thus skip password steps.

---

**2. Creating ssh-keypairs**

Again a standard operation. For both `john` and `middleman` do `ssk-keygen` - please note that `middleman` MUST have a passphrase for his RSA-key, so we achieve password authentication. This is not needed for `john` but can be done (probably in a specific RSA key for this purpose only, it just adds another password step).

---

**3. Setting up `ssh`-access with forced commands**

Now this is the interesting part: we add `john` to `middleman`'s `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with a forced command, i.e. when we access `middleman` via `ssh` from `john`, this and this command only will be executed:

```
cat /home/middleman/.ssh/authorized_keys
command="ssh -t sudouser@localhost $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" <john's public key> john@localhost
```

So this will directly initiate an ssh-session to `sudouser` forwarding the commands we specified in the first step (via `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`).

Note that this is allowed for `john` from `localhost` only - all other access is denied for security reasons. You can add forwarding restrictions via `command"...",no-port-forwarding,no-x11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding` - again for security enhancement.

And for `sudouser`'s `authorized_keys` file, we allow access from `middleman` from `localhost` only:

```
cat /home/middleman/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa <middleman's public key> middleman@localhost
```

Now in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` we lock the access down a bit:

```
Match User middleman,sudouser
    PasswordAuthentication no
    AuthenticationMethods publickey
```

So `middleman` and `sudouser` can only be access via `ssh` using RAS public keys with the forced commands given in the `authorized_keys` files. Setting `PasswordAuthentication no` might be redundant since we locked the user passwords before.

---

**4. Aliasing `sudo`**

Now the `sudo` command needs to be replaced with:

```
ssh -t middleman@localhost "sudo <command>"
```

For this a simple shell script and an alias will do:

```
#sudo_alias_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t middleman@localhost "sudo $@"
```

and
   `alias sudo='/home/john/.bin/sudo_alias_script.sh'`

---

I've successfully tried this with two middlemen. It's bulky but does what you want. If you want certain text output, you can replace the forced commands with a script that `echo`es text and then goes on to the next `ssh`-step. Whether the whole thing actually increases security is nothing I could tell.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer for your question but if you want to enhance the security you can use 2-Factor Authentication for Login and sudo.
for more info you can visit this site:

https://www.linux.com/learn/how-set-2-factor-authentication-login-and-sudo

Answer (score 0):

This does not increase security. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89533/would-requiring-multiple-passwords-enhance-security and [Will double encryption increase the security of cipher vs bruteforce?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32247/will-double-encryption-increase-the-security-of-cipher-vs-bruteforce). In a nutshell, doing more of the same cannot improve security: either what you were doing before was good and doing more is redundant, or what you were doing before was not good and doing it twice won't save you. In addition, complexity is always the enemy of security, both because it increases the risk of implementation bugs and because it reduces the chances that users will behave as you expect, so if something doesn't improve security, the cost of doing it is detrimental to security.

Asking for two passwords is the same as asking for one password, but first entering the first half and then entering the second half. By splitting the password, you've made it easier to crack, since the two halves can be cracked independently. So you have reduced security.

That being said, what you're asking can be done. **I repeat, this is a bad idea, but if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, here's how to do it. Just keep in mind that it won't make you run faster.**

On most Unix variants, authentication is configured through [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module). The PAM module that handles password authentication is [`pam_unix`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_unix.html). You can add one or more call to other password-checking modules such as [`pam_pwdfile`](https://cpbotha.net/software/pam_pwdfile/) that consult another password database (see [Is it possible to change password database file(/etc/passwd) in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42222/is-it-possible-to-change-password-database-file-etc-passwd-in-linux)).

But, once again, don't do this. **If you don't understand security, use your system's defaults instead of perverting them into something worse.**